# Trying to find the lenth of a line segment where I know the radius of a circle and the length of the intersecting object.

Tags: trigonometry

OK, new to this site, appreciate all the help. I am a screw machine operator. I am machining a threaded spacer from solid bar stock. The length of the spacer is .250". The diameter is .250 +/- .003. The part has 2 shoulders with a length of .050. The center body of the part has a length of .150. The part includes a beauty groove with a diameter of .200. I am trying to solve the length of this segment to establish a start position and an end position out to 4 decimal places(.XXXX) for this groove. The radius of the groove is .063. Hopefully the included diagram, not to scale, can help with the solution. The right side of the part, on the Z-Axis is .0. In the original program the groove started at Z-Axis .0935 and ended at .1565, working from right to left.

Thank you

[spacer drawing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EjIYA.jpg)

Comment: A drawing would help. Also definitions of terms like spacer and shoulder etc.

Answer (score 0):

Denote the width of the segment we are trying to solve by $d$ and the distance from below the segment to the bottom of the circle $a$.

Draw a line from the circle center through the perpendicular of the segment you’re trying to measure. Draw a line from the circle center to an endpoint of the segment. This should result in a right triangle with hypotenuse $R$, height $R-a$, and base $d/2$. Pythagoras then gives

\begin{align}
R^2 &= (R-a)^2+(d/2)^2\\
\implies\quad
d&=2\sqrt{R^2-(R-a)^2}=2\sqrt{a(2R-a)}
\end{align}

[image: Drawing of geometric construction]

Comment: Thank you, the formula will help when I get to run the part again and get a machined diameter.